# react-scripts build into a subdirectory

Tags: create-react-app, react-scripts

I am using create-react-app and running react-scripts build on a my project, but I'm having an issue with the build output. I need the build output to go in a subdirectory of the build folder like shown here

```
Build
-- Player
```

And I need the Urls for the generated for the JS and CSS files as shown here to include the Player in the path. I need these.

```
<link href="/static/css/main.02096f02.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.75412701.js"></script>
```

to be these

```
<link href="/player/static/css/main.02096f02.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/player/static/js/main.75412701.js"></script>
```

I need this to automate my build and deployment. Otherwise the default scripts work perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

If you set the *homepage* attribute in your `package.json` file, that will modify all the links generated in `/build/index.html`. [Here's the docs.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)

```
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `postbuild` `script` in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild" : "mv build /Player/"
}
```

Please try this.

Comment: The question is about a sub-directory on the web server, not the location of the files on your local computer.